# The Grigorcuk Group solvable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups

The description of the Grigorcuk Group is given here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grigorchuk_group. Is this group Solvable?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: [Groupprops](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Grigorchuk_group) says no. Sadly, no explanation is given.

Comment: Thanks. That all i need.

Comment: It is not hard to show that a finitely generated solvable torsion group is finite,  so the answer is no.

Comment: I think this question needs more context, in the usual way. I don't think name-dropping famous groups somehow excludes this, especially because the answer is pretty trivial (as Derek points out).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is definitely not the most straightforward solution, but it makes use of the Grigorchuk group's most famous property: having **intermediate growth**.

In [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214428658) Wolf (1968), building on a previous result by Milnor, proves that:

> A  finitely  generated  solvable  group,  either  is  polycyclic  and
>   has
>     a  nilpotent  subgroup   of  finite  index  and  is  thus  of  polynomial   growth,   or
>   has
>     no  nilpotent  subgroup  of  finite  index  and  is  of  exponential   growth.

Therefore, if the Grigorchuk group were solvable, it could not have intermediate growth.

Comment: This is overkill.  It is an easy exercise to show that a finitely generated solvable torsion group is finite.

Comment: @DerekHolt You're absolutely right. I simply like this solution because it uses the intermediate growth. Maybe you should post your solution as an answer, to give it the visibility it deserves?